# Block deployment to azure function app from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment, azure-functions

We have enabled a CI/CD pipeline using azure pipeline. Whenever someone check in to the master, the build should happen and deployment should follow. I wanted to understand how can I disallow someone to deploy to azure function web app from local visual studio

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem Sudhanshu?

Answer (score 0):

- You could use RBAC Rules which may require a lot of config work.
- Once you have CI/CD pipeline enabled, setting up RBAC(Role Based Access Control) helps to prevent users from getting the publishing profile, setting deployment credentials etc.,
- There will definitely be some config work involved in doing this because you would have to only allow permission to one user so that user could set up the service principal connection between azure and DevOps but also prevent users from creating a deployment user.

Comment: Thanks Monika. Is there a doc i can follow to setup rbac rules? I just want to disallow developers to press publish button and complete deployment from their visual studios. This is for azure functions